# How to select div including a span with specific id via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape a text of some `div` that includes a `span` with specific `id` or `class`.

for example:

```
    <div class="class1" > 
      <span id="span1"></span>
      text to scrape
    </div>
    <div class="class1" > 
      <span id="span2"></span>
      text to scrape
    </div>
    <div class="class1" > 
      <span id="span1"></span>
      text to scrape
    </div>
    <div class="class1" > 
      <span id="span3"></span>
      text to scrape
    </div>
```

I want to get the text in the div (class1) but specifically only the one witch include span (span1)

thanks

---

Thank you I have solved my problem using this code below:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for x in soup.find_all(class_='class1'):
    x_span = x.find('span',class_='span1')
    print(x_span.parent.text.strip())
```

Comment: I think at first you should change **<div/>** to  **</div>**

Answer (score 0):

this should do

```
soup.select_one('.class1:has(#span1)').text
```

Answer (score 0):

As Beso mentioned there is an typo in your `html` that should be fixed.

#### How to select?

Simplest approache in my opinion is to use a `css selector` to select all `<div>` that have a `<span>` with `class` named "span1" (cause there is more than one in your example html)

```
soup.select('div:has(> #span1)')
```

or even more specific as mentioned by diggusbickus:

```
soup.select('.class1:has(> #span1)')
```

To get the text of all of them you have to iterate the result set:

```
[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('div:has(> #span1)')]
```

That will give you a list of texts:

```
['text to scrape', 'text to scrape']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="class1" > 
  <span id="span1"></span>
  text to scrape
</div>
<div class="class1" > 
  <span id="span2"></span>
  text to scrape
</div>
<div class="class1" > 
  <span id="span1"></span>
  text to scrape
</div>
<div class="class1" > 
  <span id="span3"></span>
  text to scrape
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('div:has(> #span1)')]
```